# How to display list of items in infopath

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I have a list named Employee. It has columns of Employee Id, Employee Name, Employee Salary. 
The list has 100 records.

Now I want to show the list of data in the Employee list in infopath form like this.

```
Employee Id      Employee Name   Employee Salary
100000            Bala            1USD
200000            Bala1           1USD
300000            Bala2           1USD
```

How can I achieve this????

Comment: any reason why you want to display the data in Infopath form and not an aspx form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use repating tables. Maybe this [link](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=121) can help you.

Comment: The link have provided doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use repeating tables for the same and you have multiple ways to insert the repeating table in infopath form.

- If you have already established connection with your list just add the folder into the form as a repeating table

[image]

[Repeating Table Example](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/infopath-designer-repeating-table-example/)

- You can also add repeating table from control section and start from the scratch

[InfoPath Repeating Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-repeating-table-e313db25-fbd6-4dcd-b874-60c0b377c574)